# Textbook on Optimization

Tags: optimization, reference-request, book-recommendation

Is there any recommendation for an introductory optimization textbook?

If it covers linear programming, convex optimization and duality it would be enough. Preferably as concise (i.e., mathy, I don't need the code) as possible.

I can only find separate linear programming and convex optimization books...And most of them are 700 pages.

Comment: Convex Optimization by Boyd and Vandenberghe is good. It might seem long, but you've already learned a lot by chapter 5 on Duality, and it's hard to find a much simpler presentation of the material. Vandenberghe's UCLA 236abc notes are also worth checking out.

Comment: Yeah I know that book...Just a little too long for me. Will look at the notes. Thank you!

Comment: @failedstatistocian The trick is to not read the whole thing. Just read the small subset of it which explains what you need to know in a pretty simple way.

Comment: You can find a rather thorough set of lecture notes by one of the most prominent researchers in the study of optimization here: http://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~nemirovs/OPTILectureNotes2016.pdf There is more content available at his website; just remove the filename from the end of the above URL.

Comment: How about chapters 2, 4 and 7 (less of 100 pages) of [Linear and Nonlinear Programming](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=-pD62uvi9lgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=linear+and+nonlinear+programming&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUk6f44oLqAhVzILkGHQAIAHUQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=linear%20and%20nonlinear%20programming&f=false) by David G. Luenberger and Yinyu Ye?

Comment: Oh I have just skimmed several pages of Luenberger on Google Books. Sounds good. Thank you!